# Do we need [liars]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a tag called [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars) which, in my opinion, doesn't make any sense since the description says it's made of

1. liars,
2. truth tellers, and
3. jokers.

In other words the tag name doesn't provide all the information necessary to understand the meaning. In fact it only names 1 out of 3.

Despite the fact that I think the tag isn't needed in the first place, maybe one could change the name to "statements" or "evidence (collecting)" or something similar. Doing so would also provide a tag for all the police report puzzles at the same time.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1741/4421) might be of interest to you.  Note that the tag used to be called [tag:knights-and-knaves], and was synonymized into [tag:liars].

Comment: While it may be that there could be a better name for this tag, I think both of the suggestions you provide are *way* too broad, and could encompass any number of things that aren't truth-teller/liar questions.  If the tag is going to change, I think you need to come up with a better option.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, we need the tag.

Logic puzzles which revolve around extracting information from liars and truth-tellers have been an established part of puzzling culture for decades. Puzzling gurus such as Martin Gardner, Ian Stewart, and Raymond Smullyan have written extensively about them, and they're clearly distinguishable from other types of logic puzzles (such as, for example, puzzles involving logicians wearing hats, or the logic-grid puzzles which are sometimes known as Einstein's puzzles).

---

So what about the *name* of the tag?

I don't agree with your premise that the name is bad because there are three kinds of people involved in such puzzles. Much of the time there are only two kinds of people - the Jokers are an occasional twist, but there are [many](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41972/5373) different [kinds](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/43092/5373) of [twists](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/10289/5373) in these puzzles, so I don't think Jokers deserve any more special consideration than any of these other variations on the main theme of liars and truth-tellers. Furthermore, if there were only truth-tellers, there wouldn't be much of a puzzle (or at least, the methods used to solve the puzzle would be entirely different and it would no longer be the same type of puzzle). So it's the **liars** that really define such puzzles and make them interesting, which is why I think it's reasonable to use the tag [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars) for them.

However, I can see your point. If there were only liars, the puzzle would be little more interesting than if there were only truth-tellers. What makes such puzzles challenging is that there are *both* liars *and* truth-tellers. And funnily enough, the [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars) already has a [synonym](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/liars/synonyms): [knights-and-knaves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-and-knaves). So here's a counter-proposal for you:

### how about reversing the synonym to make [knights-and-knaves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-and-knaves) the main tag?

That way, both liars and truth-tellers are referred to in the tag name, which alleviates your concern about the [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars) tag only mentioning one of them. And the synonymisation would stay, so by typing "liar" into the tag box, people would still find this tag.

On the other hand, the name "knights and knaves" is sort of memetic, and relies on people having heard of Raymond Smullyan's specific phrasing for such logic puzzles, whereas "liars" is more general and instantly understandable without making reference to specific puzzling authors.

---

As a (slightly) separate issue, the tag wiki should certainly be rewritten. It shouldn't refer to Jokers as if they're an essential part of such puzzles, and it probably shouldn't even use the Knights/Knaves terminology since that's too specific. Deusovi has already addressed this in [his answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5537/5373).

Comment: I'd +1 for the first part, but I don't agree with the second. [liars-and-truthtellers] perhaps, but knights/knaves relies on knowledge of one specific formulation.

Comment: To address your last paragraph:  If the [tag:liars] synonym remains, that point is kind of moot.  People looking to tag their own puzzles or search for puzzles can still easily find the tag using [tag:liars], and those reading and solving the puzzles don't really need the tag, since the content of the puzzle makes it abundantly evident.

Comment: @Deusovi Yes, that's the same doubt I expressed in my final paragraph. Would [tag:liars-and-truthtellers] come within the character limit for tags?

Answer (score 4):

A "liars and truthtellers puzzle" (or "knights and knaves") is a puzzle where several people make different statements about each other and external events, and your job is to deduce either which of the people always tell the truth and which always lie, or some external information (like who stole something, or what the right path to go down is).

Sometimes "jokers" or random answerers are added, but not usually.

I think it's a distinct enough genre to merit its own tag - I don't see why we *wouldn't* have a tag for it, in any case. The wiki probably should be updated though.